# Como generar un PDF a partir de un archivo PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf

LLevo rato intentando buscar la solucion pero no la encuentro. Tengo un archivo PHP donde tengo cierto contenido que me ha creado unos bucles y unos aleatorios, por ejemplo:

La mesa 1 tiene 5 comensales (0 sillas vacias)

La mesa 2 tiene 2 comensales (3 sillas vacias)

La mesa 3 tiene 4 comensales (1 sillas vacias)

La mesa 4 tiene 4 comensales (1 sillas vacias)

La mesa 5 tiene 5 comensales (0 sillas vacias)

Bueno, pues lo que quiero es que este contenido se me almacene en un PDF para poder descargarlo y hasta ahora lo unico que he conseguido es esto, y dandome errores:

```
    <?php
    $mesas=$_GET["mesas"];
    $pers=$_GET["pers"];
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<br/><h1>Restaurante Valero</h1>";
    echo "<div style='border:1px solid;padding:100px;margin:50px;'>";
    for ($i=1; $i < $mesas+1; $i++) {
      $aleat = rand(0, $pers);
      $sillas = $pers-$aleat;
        if ($aleat == 0) {
          echo "La mesa $i esta vacia ($sillas sillas vacias)";
        }
        else {
          echo "La mesa $i tiene $aleat comensales ($sillas sillas vacias)";
        }
      echo "<br/>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    $pdf->Output();

    ?>
```

Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola **Esteban Valero** que error te sale

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Practica1\Ejercicio1\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Practica1\Ejercicio1\fpdf\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Practica1\Ejercicio1\fpdf\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Practica1\Ejercicio1\ejercicio1B.php(35): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Practica1\Ejercicio1\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271

Comment: `fpdf` es una librería muy básica. No tiene por ejemplo métodos propios para crear contenido basado en HTML, para lo cual tendrás que crear tú mismo una clase o método que haga de *parser* (ver [ejemplo 1](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php) o [ejemplo 2](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php)). Otra opción es que hagas uso de una librería más completa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola si bien con **echo** muestras el **html** en el navegador, en ningún momento cargas los datos a tu variable **$pdf**, por otra parte si cargarías todo tu contenido **html** en un string y se lo pasa a **fpdf**, este imprimirá el string en texto plano, dicho de otro modo no transformara tu html a texto.
Para hacerlo tienes que crear una función que te reciba el **html** que desees convertir a texto, y traducir las etiquetas a su equivalente en **fpdf**.

Ejemplo

```
escribir(“<h1>Texto en html</h1>”)
{
//aquí procesas el html para obtener el texto y los tag
tag=H1
texto= “Texto en html”

Si tag==H1 
entonces 
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',20); //20 es el tamaño del texto
   $pdf->Cell(40,10,$Texto);

deloContrario
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10); //20 es el tamaño del texto
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,$Texto);
```

**El código de tu pregunta quedaría asi usando los métodos de la librería.**

```php
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

function contenido()
{
    $mesas= 5; //$_GET["mesas"];
    $pers=5; //$_GET["pers"];
    $datos="";
    for ($i=1; $i < $mesas+1; $i++) {
      $aleat = rand(0, $pers);
      $sillas = $pers-$aleat;
        if ($aleat == 0) {
          $datos.="La mesa $i esta vacia ($sillas sillas vacias)"."\n";
        }
        else {
          $datos.="La mesa $i tiene $aleat comensales ($sillas sillas vacias)"."\n";
        }
    }
    return $datos;
}



$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Restaurante Valero');
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->MultiCell(180, 10, contenido(), 1, 'C',false);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

[image: imajen]

Para esta ya hay algunos  [Scripts](http://www.fpdf.org/)  creados y puedes revisar la documentacion [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/index.php), [aqui](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php) hay un script que hace la traducción, tendrías que aumentar codigo y adaptarlo a tus requerimientos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, conseguí que me saliera!!!

Comment: ok! me alegra .